# a function called inside a procedure with arguments passed by reference not working properly in c language

Tags: c, pointers, reference, arguments

I used x as an integer variable and defined this procedure that calls another procedure. The &x in choix_pion is probably causing issues to the code. How can I fix it? Or should I rather declare x as an integer pointer and fix that?

Here is the code:
In the main procedure, I defined x and y this way:
int x=0, y=0;

```
void tester_remplir_matrice(char matrice[][DIMENSION+1],char jeton, char *joueur, int *x, int *y ,char lettres[], char nombres[])
{
    if (matrice[*x][*y]=='.') /*tester si l'intersection ets vide cad contient '.'*/
    {
        matrice[*x][*y]=jeton;
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        do {
            printf("\tLa place est deja occupee!");
            choix_pion(joueur,jeton,&x,&y,lettres,nombres);/*on lui demande de réexprimer
                                                             son choix où placer son pion*/
        }while(matrice[*x][*y]!='.');
        matrice[*x][*y]=jeton;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the cod of choix_pion:

```
void choix_pion(char *joueur,char jeton_couleur,int *x,int *y,char lettres[], char nombres[])
{

    char choix[3];
    char limite_lettre[3]={'A'+DIMENSION-1,'\0'};
    printf("\t%s vous etes le jeton %c\n\n \tChoisissez une place XY ou X:A-I et Y:1-9 = ",joueur,jeton_couleur);
    scanf("%s",choix);
    printf("\n");
    if ((strcmp(choix,"A")>=0) && (strcmp(choix,limite_lettre)<=0 )&& ( (strcmp(choix+1,"1")>=0)  && (strcmp(choix+1,"DIMENSION")<=0))) /*vérifier si le jouer
       n'a pas choisi des places hors le cadre du goban de A--I et 1--9 dans el cas de 9*9*/
    {
            for(int i=0;i<DIMENSION;i++)
            {
                if(lettres[i]==choix[0])
                {
                   *y=i;
                   printf("done");
                }

            }

            for(int i=0;i<DIMENSION;i++)
            {
                if (nombres[i]==choix[1])
                   *x=i;
            }
        }


   else
    printf("Veuillez choisir une place appartenant a l'intervalle donne!");

}
```

Comment: How is `choix_pion` defined?

Comment: What is does `choix_pion` do with the parameter? `x` is the address of the pointer, not the address of the caller's `int` variable that it refers to.

Comment: @Elas It seems you need to call the function like choix_pion(joueur,jeton,x,y,...

Comment: The `&x` and `&y` in the code presented are pointers to pointers. Specifically, type `int **`.  It's unclear what type `choix_pion()` expects them to have, or how it uses them, but if it expects a different type then that is likely the locus of the problem.

Comment: _"I used x as an integer variable"_ - No, you didn't. `int *x` declares x as a pointer to an int.

Comment: Note well that C does not have references or pass by reference.  It does have passing pointers by value, which is what this function's caller does with respect to most of the function parameters.  This point is often considered pedantic, but it may factor in to why you think it makes sense to pass `&x` and `&y` on to `choix_pion()`, as opposed to passing plain `x` and `y`.  I don't have enough information to be sure which is right, but my bet would be on the latter.

Comment: You can do it either way, but if you pass `&x` and the function wants to increment the integer, it needs to `**x++`.

Comment: I assume `choix_pion()` is supposed to update `x` and `y`, otherwise the condition `while(matrice[*x][*y]!='.')` will be an infinite loop.

Comment: @dbush, I added the definition of this procedure as well, note that x and y I defined them as integer variables in the man procedure and not pointers

Comment: @Barmar I added the definition of this procedure as well, note that x and y I defined them as integer variables in the man procedure and not pointers

Answer (score 0):

```
choix_pion(joueur,jeton,&x,&y,lettres,nombres)
```

Here you do not pass pointer only pointer to pointer  (as `x` && `y` are already pointers) which was not your intention.

You need to:

```
choix_pion(joueur,jeton,x,y,lettres,nombres)
```

Comment: I  have declared x and y as integer variables, not pointers and I called them by reference in **tester_remplir_matrice(...,)**

Comment: @Elas no, you did not . The calling function: `void tester_remplir_matrice(char matrice[][DIMENSION+1],char jeton, char *joueur, int *x, int *y ,char lettres[], char nombres[])` They are obviously pointers.

Comment: @Elas You are probably confused by the same names. But they are completely different. declarations in main do not matter in those function scopes